# BroadcastReceiver for Screen On/Off in ANDROID When App is not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to detect screen off and on event for that i have created BroadcastReceiver, It only works fine when app is running and when i remove the app from task manager then it does not works.

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try{
        BroadcastReceiver myrcver  = new BootReceiver();
        IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
        screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(myrcver, screenStateFilter);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.fillInStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Menifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Broadcast Reciever:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
boolean screenOff;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        if ("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                screenOff = true;
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                screenOff = false;
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
            i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.fillInStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Help is appreciate in advance.

Comment: "It only works fine when app is running and when i remove the app from task manager then it does not works" -- correct. Those are two of a handful of broadcasts that are only delivered to running processes that use `registerReceiver()`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want it to run in the background even if the app is not running, you will have to create a Service.
In the Service class you will have to register to your Receiver.

```
public class ScreenOnOffService extends Service {

    private ScreenOnOffReceiver mScreenReceiver;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerScreenStatusReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterScreenStatusReceiver();
    }

    private void registerScreenStatusReceiver() {
        mScreenReceiver = new ScreenOnOffReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        registerReceiver(mScreenReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void unregisterScreenStatusReceiver() {
        try {
            if (mScreenReceiver != null) {
                unregisterReceiver(mScreenReceiver);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
    }
}
```

After creating the service class don't forget to add your service to the Manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.myapp.services.ScreenOnOffService" />
```

Then to start the service you can write this in your main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenOnOffService.class);
startService(intent);
```

For the broadcast class:

```
public class ScreenOnOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.d("StackOverflow", "Screen Off");

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.d("StackOverflow", "Screen On");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: for me the `screen off` and `screen on` ,did **NOT** work inside the manifest , but only at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I already tried this, It wont work when app is closed

Comment: Did you remember to register the service in the AndroidManifest? 
<service android:name="com.myapp.services.ScreenOnOffService" />

Comment: Yes i did, I have registered it

Comment: I've added more details to my answer. i'm not sure why it is not working for you, but i run what i wrote here and it is working for me. make sure that your service is running. also, creating this receiver in the Manifest like you did, did NOT work for me. only when i added the intent filters programmatically i received intents in the broadcast.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late for the party but might help someone. 
Do as mentioned by @CookieMonster above, further while starting your service **ScreenOnOffService** , do like this

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(new Intent(this, ScreenOnOffService.class));
    } else {
        startService(new Intent(this, ScreenOnOffService.class));
    }
```

and in your **ScreenOnOffService** onCreate() method paste the below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "your_channel_id";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Notification Channel Title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("").build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
```

now run your application. It will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks this is very important when supporting versions past Android Oreo

Answer (score -2):

Broad cast reciever can run when app is not running only if you add permission wake.lock in your manifest